# Error 4 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'char *'

Tags: compilation

I tried to compile this and got mistakes such as:

```
Error   4   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'char *'
```

This code is taken from [here](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/29190-memory-scanningediting/). Why doesn't it work?

```
DWORD dwRead=0;

char *lpData = (VOID*)GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, MAX_READ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be compiling with a C++ compiler, so you'll need an explicit cast:

```
char *lpData = (char *)GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, MAX_READ);
```

Comment: Hi thanks) Yes already did it now comes another error C2065: 'dwSize' : undeclared identifier. Should i include any libraries ?