# Error C2440 initializing cannot convert void to typ

Tags: c, malloc, structure

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
// self - referential structure
struct listNode {
char data; // each listNode contains a character
struct listNode *nextPtr; //pointer to next node
};

typedef struct listNode ListNode;  // synonym for struct listNode
typedef ListNode *ListNodePtr; // synonym for struct listnode*



void insert(ListNodePtr *sPtr, char value)
{
ListNodePtr newPtr = malloc(sizeof(ListNode)); // create node

if (newPtr != NULL) // is space availale?
{
    newPtr->data = value; // place value in node
    newPtr->nextPtr = NULL; // node does not link to another node

     ListNodePtr previousPtr = NULL;
    ListNodePtr currentPtr = *sPtr;

    // loop to find the correct location in the list
     while (currentPtr != NULL && value > currentPtr->data)
     {
        previousPtr = currentPtr; // walk to...
         currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr; // ... next node
     }

    if (previousPtr == NULL) // insert new node at beginning of list
     {
        newPtr->nextPtr = *sPtr;
        *sPtr = newPtr;
    }
    else
    {
        previousPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
        newPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr;
    }
}

else 
{
    printf("%c not inserted. No memory available. \n", value);
}
}
```

this is my function, the problem happens in line 
"ListNodePtr newPtr = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));" 
It says Cannoy convert void to ListNotePtr
Then it says
IntelliSense: A value of type "void *" cannoy be used to initialize entity of type "ListNodePtr"

I'm a bit confused because I copied this function straight from my lecture slides, but I cannot seem to make it work. Anybody know what's going on? This function and others are called in main(void). 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you compiling as C++ by chance?

Comment: I seem to  You be using  C++ compiler as  C compiler. Change the options (to use C) or use cast.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2013, but that might be it. I made a cpp file instead of a .c

Comment: it still threw the same error :/

Comment: Actually, I repeated the experiment in a new project (so I could ensure I was working with C and not C++) and it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that you are assigning a void type value to a ListNodePtr variable.
If you are compiling with a C++ compiler, you need to perform an explicit cast:

```
void insert(ListNodePtr *sPtr, char value)
{
    ListNodePtr newPtr = (ListNodePtr)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
// ...
```

There is a similar issue here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15106036/5810934.

Answer (score 0):

This will work hopefully

```
ListNodePtr* newPtr = static_cast<ListNodePtr*>(malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
```

Answer (score 0):

The owner's problem has been solved; however, after thinking about it, I decided to share possibly another reason to offer to those who come later.

I encountered the same error; the reason is that my code piece is as follows

```
QMenu* m_menu = new QMenu(this);
QAction* actCopy = m_menu->addAction(new QAction(tr("Copy")));
```

After checking the Qt Assistant, I found that it was an incoming parameter error

```
QAction* actCopy = m_menu->addAction(tr("Copy"));
```